# Do all monarch caterpillars have two pairs of needle-shaped protrusions(or they can have three pairs)?

Tags: species-identification

I found this [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Monarch_butterfly_Caterpillar.jpg):

[image]

Is this a monarch caterpillar?
Do all monarch caterpillars have two pairs of needle-shaped protrusions?

[image]

Comment: Just a guess, but it may be species-dependent on whether they have 2 or 3 pairs of protrusions/antennae. Your first image is of *Danaus chrysippus*, while your lower image is of two other species.

Comment: @MattDMo Danaus chrysippus and Danaus gilippus caterpillars are very similar. Quite difficult to distinguish.